# Im trying to find a css hack for just safari NOT chrome

Tags: css, safari

Im trying to find a css hack for just safari NOT chrome, i know these are both webkit browsers but im having problems with div alignments in chrome and safari, each displays differently.

i have been trying to use this but it affects chrome as well,

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
```

#safari {  } 
} 
does anyone know of another one that will just apply to safari please?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a media-query hack to select Safari 7+ from other browsers.

```
@media \\0 screen {}
```

*Disclaimer: This hack also targets old Chrome versions (before July 2013).*

Tips: I found it on the [browserhacks](http://browserhacks.com) website.